# Отправка формы Ajax, Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки данных. Использую Ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#form').on('click', '#button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var comParent = $ (this);
        $ ('.wrap_result').css('color', 'white').text('Коментарий сохранен').fadeIn(500, function() {
            var data = $ ('#form').serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url:$ ('#form').attr('action'),
                data:data,
                type:'POST',
                datatype:'JSON',
                success: function() {

                },
                error: function() {

                }

            })
        })
    })
});
```

Шаблон формы

```
<form class="comment-area" method="POST" action="{{route('store')}}" id="form">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input type="hidden" id="comment_post_id" name="comment_post_id" value="{{$article->id}}">
                            @if (!Auth::check())
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Your URL">
                            </div>
                            @endif
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <button class="full-btn" id="button">Добавить комментарий </button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Код контроллера

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\menu;
    class CommentController extends SiteController
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            dd($request);
        }
    }
```

Объявление роута:

```
Route::post('comment', 'CommentController@store')->name('store');
```

После нажатия кнопки в консоли ловлю следующую ошибку

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Вот что я вижу переходя по самой ссылке:
[image: Переход по ссылке]

У кого какие соображения?

Comment: роут нужно писать в `api.php`

Comment: Сделал по инструкции, все удобно расписано https://offgalaxy.com/ajax-form-laravel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, при переходе по указанному в браузере ты получаешь правильную ошибку - неправильный метод, т.к. маршрут у тебя POST, а ты своим переходом осуществляешь GET запрос.

Во-вторых, при использовании хелпера `dd` всегда возвращается html (не `json`) ответ с кодом 500. Соответственно большинство http клиентов, в т.ч. `jquery.ajax` выкидывают ошибку, если статус ответа больше 400. Если хочешь увидеть, что прилетело на сервер - используй либо dump-server (просто в консоли `php artisan dump-server`) совместно с dump() вместо dd(), второй вариант - используй пакет [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) + хелпер debug() вместо dd()

Есть разные варианты дебага, один из них указанный выше `dump-server`, если интересует, что летит на сервер с клиента - консоль браузера на вкладке "сеть", если надо продебажить в том числе sql запросы к БД в контексте текущего HTTP зпроса - тут очень удобен https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar - там и ошибки, и сообщения, и емейлы, и память запроса - вобщем очень много полезной информации о каждом запросе, в т.ч. и о ajax запросах

Comment: Спасибо, завтра тоже посмотрю и отпишусь

Comment: Вы были правы, ошибка пропала, но я не могу понять как все таки мне посмотреть что пришло на сервер...

Comment: Я не могу php artisan dump-server, команда не найдена

Comment: Этот пакет по умолчанию входит в laravel 5.7 из коробки, но нет ничего сложно в его установке: `composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server` https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server

Comment: Все равно не выходит.... Что то с установкой не так http://prntscr.com/mzcxnd

Comment: Но ничего, я смог посмотреть что приходит через f12

Comment: Это достаточно странно. Пакет установлен? Версия лары какая? Если до 5.5, то надо будет сервис-провайдер вручную добавить

Answer (score 0):

`$('#form').on('click', '#button', function(e) {` на `$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {` замените

Или на

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e)
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую и отпишусь